# CSS: Why is there something grey strange in Safari?

Tags: css, safari

Is there anyone knows how to remove the grey layer (cf [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt1td.png)
) in Safari ? There is no such problem in Chrome.

The structure is like:

```
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">
      <select>
        ...
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
.class1 {border: solid 1px #...; background-color:white; border-radius:50%; ...}
.class2 {background: 0 0; border:none; ... }
```

I think it should add something in class2 style to remove the grey layer.

Comment: its better to upload the image properly thank link to it in case the hosting provider goes down. plus... noones got the time to click the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `appearance: none;` to your `select`.

Think that might be the problem

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there is already apperance:none; -moz-apprearance:none; -o-apprearance:none;

Comment: In fact, it should add -webkit-apperance:none. Thanks a lot